# Jenkins build failure for python script in github using ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: scripts, python, git, github, jenkins

I created a simple python code in my github repo with the following:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as plt
a=np.arange(1,5).reshape(4,1) 
print(a)
print(a.data)
print(a**2)
print(a.dtype)
```

I integrated my GitHub with Jenkins.

I build a job with freestyle project name it project1.

I put my repo url in the scm and my credential.

I used build trigger as GitHub hook.

In the build step I used shell script

```
python3 numpy.py
```

saved it and when trying to build it  shows failure

saying no module matplotlib and numpy linag something like this.

Why I am not able to build it.

I am using ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS

What should I write in the execution shell

Comment: Is there any Ubuntu product involved?

Comment: I am using ubuntu and wrote and run the code on PyCharm and then created a GitHub repo. While trying to build and test it showed failure

Comment: Then in the question it needs to say the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: In the question with the edit command not as a comment.

Comment: What may be the issue in my setup brother. Can you help me out here?